# Adding the count of two related fields in django

Tags: django, django-models

Maybe I'm not searching right, but I haven't found this yet...

I have three models. Here are two, the other is the User model:

```
class Comment(Model(20)):
    text = TextField(max_length=160)

class Look(Model(20)):
    comments = ManyToManyField(Comment, related_name='comments', editable=False)
    likes = ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name="look_likes", editable=False)
```

Now I want to order my Looks by the total of likes and comments (Count(likes) + Count(comments)).

I've tried:

```
most_wanted = Look.objects.all()
most_wanted = most_wanted.annotate(count_comments=Count('comments'))
most_wanted = most_wanted.annotate(count_likes=Count('likes'))
most_wanted = most_wanted.extra(select = { 'count': 'count_comments + count_likes' })
```

But the annotated fields don't work with extra. I also tried:

```
most_wanted = Look.objects.all()
most_wanted = most_wanted.extra(select = { 'count': 'Count(comments) + Count(likes)' })
```

But related fields (from ManyToMany) don't work with extra either.

Any thoughs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that in the query. But there doesn't seem to be a need to: it's a simple addition, it can be done in Python.

Comment: I forgot to mention I want to sort the data according to that field!